# pythonic solution for finding the other element in a list of length two

Tags: python

I have a list which contains a pair. For example

```
pair = ['x', 'xc']
```

The problem is given `x` I need to find `xc` and vice-versa. I have the following code to achieve it. I am using Python 2.2 (don't ask). Any cleaner solution will be instructive.

```
def getComplement(pair, core):
    complement = None       
    for element in pair:
       if element != core:
         complement = element

    return complement

print getComplement(['x', 'xc'], 'xc') # 'x'
print getComplement(['x', 'xc'], 'x')  # 'xc'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ummm

```
return pair[0] if pair[0] != core else pair[1]
```

or

```
return set(pair) - [core]
```

or

```
return  pair[not pair.index(core)]
```

theres lots of other ways also

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible approach:

```
def getComplement(pair, core):
    if core not in pair:
        return None
    return pair[0] if pair[1] == core else pair[1]
```

It is fairly self-explanatory!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you that pair = ['x', 'xc'] and you are given either core='x' or core='xc' then

```
if core == pair[0]:
    return pair[1]
else:
    return pair[0]
```